# SQL Server query select min over partition by

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have some hard time to understand this over select partition by statement. I read about it but don't get it. What's the benefit of using:

```
SELECT MIN(Field) OVER (PARTITION BY OtherField) as Value
FROM MYTABLE
```

Can you briefly describe this, when will you use it and why? What's the benefit and the acheivement goal when you write something like this

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect the result?

Comment: Voting to close as too broad.

Comment: As posted, it has little benefit IMO. StepUp has posted a good explanation but with a different context - notice the other column in that example that makes the query useful.

Answer (score 10):

`OVER (PARTITION BY OtherField)` is a window function.  In addition, the main idea it to group by partitions **without** reducing of count of selected table rows.

In general, window functions are going to be faster than join/aggregation solutions. This is a rather simple case, so the performance might be essentially the same.

Let me show an example:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Duration     (startDate datetime2, endDate datetime2);

INSERT INTO dbo.Duration (startDate, endDate)  VALUES ('2007-05-06 16:42:09', '2007-05-07 11:10:08');  
INSERT INTO dbo.Duration (startDate, endDate)  VALUES ('2007-05-07 08:30:09', '2007-05-07 12:12:43');  
INSERT INTO dbo.Duration (startDate, endDate)  VALUES ('2007-05-07 11:35:09', '2007-05-07 17:13:39');  
INSERT INTO dbo.Duration (startDate, endDate)  VALUES ('2007-05-07 08:30:10', '2007-05-07 12:12:43');  
INSERT INTO dbo.Duration (startDate, endDate)  VALUES ('2007-05-07 08:30:11', '2007-05-07 12:12:43');  
INSERT INTO dbo.Duration (startDate, endDate)  VALUES ('2007-05-07 08:30:12', '2007-05-07 12:12:43');
```

Now we can make partitions by field `EndDate` and get the `MIN()` of startDate`in the partition of`EndDate`:

```
SELECT 
MIN(dr.startDate)  OVER (PARTITION BY dr.endDate ) MinDateByPartitionOfEndDate
,  dr.endDate
FROM dbo.Duration dr
```

Pay great attention to `2007-05-07 12:12:43` and their values `2007-05-07 08:30:09.0000000`. So we did not reduce the query result, however we got `MIN` value of each partition by desired field.

OUTPUT:

```
MinDateByPartitionOfEndDate    endDate
2007-05-06 16:42:09.0000000    2007-05-07 11:10:08.0000000
2007-05-07 08:30:09.0000000    2007-05-07 12:12:43.0000000
2007-05-07 08:30:09.0000000    2007-05-07 12:12:43.0000000
2007-05-07 08:30:09.0000000    2007-05-07 12:12:43.0000000
2007-05-07 08:30:09.0000000    2007-05-07 12:12:43.0000000
2007-05-07 11:35:09.0000000    2007-05-07 17:13:39.0000000
2007-05-07 11:35:09.0000000    2007-05-07 17:13:39.0000000
```

And a `GROUP BY` query to see a main difference between `GROUP BY` and `PARTITION BY` (it **reduces** the query result):

```
SELECT 
MIN(dr.startDate) MinDateByGroupBy
,  dr.endDate
FROM dbo.Duration dr
GROUP BY dr.endDate
```

OUTPUT:

```
MinDateByGroupBy                    endDate
2007-05-06 16:42:09.0000000     2007-05-07 11:10:08.0000000
2007-05-07 08:30:09.0000000     2007-05-07 12:12:43.0000000
2007-05-07 11:35:09.0000000     2007-05-07 17:13:39.0000000
```